# Set default value in model Ruby on Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have model `Comment` with these methods:

```
def self.get_article_comments(id, limit, offset)
 joins("LEFT JOIN articles ON comments.commentable_type = 'Article' AND comments.commentable_id = articles.id")
.joins("LEFT JOIN users ON comments.user_id = users.id")
    .select('comments.user_id, users.avatar, comments.comment, users.name')
    .where(["articles.id= ?", id])
    .order('comments.id DESC').limit(limit).offset(offset)
end

def set_avatar
  self.avatar ||= self.user.avatar_url
end
```

I want to set avatar for each user (set_avatar method), but only if it is `null` in users table.
What I try is this:

```
  after_initialize :set_avatar, unless: :persisted?
```

, but because `avatar` column is not part of comments table I am getting this error:

> undefined method `avatar' for Comment:0x00007ff37eb87198>

, in some of the controller methods where I am not using `get_article_comments`.

`self.user.avatar_url` - `avatar_url` is from `Carrierwave`gem with which I am getting user avatar.

Yes, there is a way to do that in the controller method or in `get_article_comments` method where I can loop the result, check and set `avatar`, but is there more clear way ?

For the example, is there way to execute `set_avatar` after selecting data for specific methods only ?

EDIT

I am using default value for `Carrierwave` uploader, but it doesn't work with this query and `avatar` is `null`.

Comment: why should a `Comment` set the avatar? The `avatar` should be loaded from the `User`

Comment: Yes, but I am using Ajax to load the comments with JSON response like {comment:'comment', avatar:'path', username:'name of the user'}, {}. I have in the controller method: `@comments = Comment.get_article_comments(params[:id], params[:limit], params[:offset])` and returning this: `render json: @comments`. If there is a better way to implement this, please share it.

Comment: Why dont you set default value in db column?

Comment: I would consider changing your `json` to `render json: @comments.as_json (include: { user: {only: [:username, :avatar]} })`

Comment: Yes, this good way to do, but I need to know is user has uploaded avatar.

Comment: then either validate that they do when they are created or set a default avatar when they don't e.g. `attribute :avatar, default: "some/local/asset/avatar.jpg"`

Comment: This will add value `some/local/asset/avatar.jpg` to the column `avatar` , and I can't check that user has uploaded avatar. I have and default avatar in the `Carrierwave` uploader.

Comment: What I did for now is: `comments.map{|c| c.avatar = c.user.avatar_url}`, but may be is better to set default in database. I will stay with `map` for now, if I can't find other way.

Answer (score 0):

> One class uses the internal fields and methods of another class.

This above is the definition of a code smell called "Inappropriate Intimacy".

You could instead have a method in the User class that would force a default value on the avatar field or a default on the DB schema.

Why not have a default like Carrierwave suggests?

```
class MyUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  def default_url(*args)
    ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_'))
  end
end
```

Comment: It is not working with the query. I don't know why, but avatar is null. I have default value for avatar in Carrierwave uploader and it is working in other queries.